# Homomorphism defined by a function

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_{143} \to\mathbb Z_{11} \times\mathbb Z_{13}$ be an homomorphism
>   and define $f$ by $f(x) = (x\mod11, x \mod13).$ Determine an $x\in
>  \mathbb{Z}_{143}$ such that $f(x) = (7,4).$

I got that $x\mod 11 = 7$ and that $x\mod13=4$ so this implies $x = 7 + 11q$ and $x = 4 + 13r$ for some $q$ and $r$. Thus combining the two I got $4+13r = 7 + 11q$ therefore $3 = 13r - 11q.$

Here is where I got stuck (need to review number theory again and Euclid of Alexandria).

How can I find my $q$ and $r$ and complete the problem?

Comment: *Hints:* $7+11q = 4+13q + 3-2q$ and $-13 = 3 - 2\cdot 8$.

Comment: the easy way is to list all numbers congruent to 7 mod 11.  You eventually come to 95, which is 4 mod 13 since 95 = 7*13+4

Comment: Your initial phrase has a problem: you cannot say "Let $f$ be ... and define $f$ by ...". Either you let $f$ be anything satisfying the requirement, **or** you define $f$ precisely. In the current case it happens that there is only one $f$ that is is homomorphism (of unitary rings), but your sentence must choose its point of view. I would suggest "Let $f$ be _the_ homomorphism ... defined by ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a solution to the system of congruences

$$\begin{align*}x&=7\pmod {11}\\
x&=4\pmod{13}\end{align*}$$

Mimic (one of) the Chinese Remainder Theorem's proofs: we want to find $\;t\in\Bbb Z\;$ s.t. $\;7+11t=4\pmod {13}\;$ since then $\;x:=7+11t\;$ solves our problem (why?):

$$11t=4-7=-3=10\pmod{13}\implies$$

$$\implies t=10\cdot 11^{-1}\pmod{13}=10\cdot 6=60=8\pmod{13}$$

So take $\;x=11\cdot 8+7=95\;\ldots$

Comment: Don, how did you get that $$t=10\cdot 11^{-1}\pmod{13}=10\cdot 6?$$

Comment: @Lays : $\;\;11\cdot 6 = 66 =13\cdot 5 + 1 =1 \pmod{13}\implies 11^{-1}=6\pmod{13}\;$

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of simultaneous congruences, the Chinese remainder theorem is your friend. But you must of course know a version that shows how to effectively get a solution.

To get a not too large answer for $x$, I suggest to put $y=x-4$ and solve for $y$ first; you are now given $y\equiv3\pmod{11}$ and $y\equiv0\pmod{13}$. So you need a multiple $13k$ of $13$ that gives remainder $3$ modulo $11$; since $13$ itself gives remainder $2$, you need to solve $2k\equiv3\pmod{11}$ which you can do almost at sight by $k=7$ (or $k=-4$). You get $y=91$ and $x=95$ (or $y=-52$ and $x=-48$).

In general you will after simplification need to solve a congrence of the type $ax=b\pmod{n}$ for some $a,b,n$ (here $(a,b,n)=(2,3,11)$). The systematic way to do this is to compute $d=\gcd(a,n)$ while finding (a Bezout coefficient) $s$ such that $d\equiv sa\pmod n$; now either $d$ divides $b$ and $x=(b/d)s$ is a solution, or $d$ does not divide $b$ and there will be no solution, since further reduction modulo$~d$ gives the impossible congruence $0x\equiv b\pmod d$.

Comment: I don't think I have learned Chinese remainder theorem but I should take the time to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually we calculate $gcd$ of $13,11$ as follows :

$13=1.11+2$

$11=5.2+1$

$2=2.1+0$

Now, as you know $(13,11)=1$ you are sure that there exists $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $13m+11n=1$

Now, $1=11-5.2=11-5(13-11)=11+5.11-5.13=6.11-5.13$

If you have  $1=6.11-5.13$, can you find $r,q$ such that $3=13r-11q$???

> just by multiplying by 3 on both sides $3=18.11-15.13=13(-15)-11(-18)$

Comment: I am not sure how you got 

$$13=1.11+2,
11=5.2+1,
2=2.1+0?$$

Comment: It is another way of calculating g c d... if you are not familiar with this kind of calculation... you may avoid it,,,

Comment: I will look it up. Thanks for the help!